# How to add values in excel sheet through microsoft access and choosing specific sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel file with many different sheets.

I was wondering how I can open the workbook, and input a value into a specific cell and choosing which sheet it goes in using visual basic (Microsoft access)

Also, some of my sheets have names like 'part 1 test', how do I account for the extra spaces in the name?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    Dim oExcel As Object
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim CurrentColumn As Integer

    'Make a new instance of Excel
    Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    'Have that instance open your workbook
    oExcel.Open("YourWorkBookName")

    'Open the database
    Set db = CurrentDb
    'Create a SQL result from a SQL string to pull data from your database
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(YourSQLString)

    'Assign the value of a field in your SQL output to a cell

    oExcel.Workbook("YourWorkBookName").Sheets("YourSheetName").Cell(YourCellRow, YourCellColumn") = rs.("FieldName")
```

The spaces in your sheet name shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, how will oExcel.Open() Know the location?

Comment: I put oExcel.Open("Workbookname") and it says  that Object doesn't support this property or method